# BLT instruction unknown in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, instructions

I was getting an error on line 19 saying error at blt unknown. I really don't a lot about the MIPS processor

```
.data
   A:      .word 4,8,12,16,20,24,28
   Message:   .ascii " The Sum is:"
.text
   li $t0,0                # load immediate value 0 to regiter $t0
   li $t1,7       # load immediate value 7 to regiter $t1
   li $t3,2       # load immediate value 2 to regiter $t3
   la $t2,A       # load address of array to regiter $t2
   li $s0,0       # load immediate value 0 to regiter $so to hold sum value
calSum:
   div $t5,$t0,$t3            # Divide $t0 with $t1 and store result in $t2
   mfhi $t4               # remainder to $t4
   bnez $t4,X2       # If remainder is not zero then jump to label X2
   lw $t6,0($t2)       # Store zeroth element of array register $t6
   add $s0,$s0,$t6       # Add this to sum in register $s0
X2:
   addi $t2,$t2,4       # If index is not divisible by 2 then point to next element
   addi $t0,$t0,1       # Increment index
   blt $t0,$t1,calSum   # Repeat from label calSum
   li  $v0, 4          # To print message use system call
   la  $a0, Message
   syscall
   move $a0,$s0           # print result stored in register $s0
   li $v0,1       # System call to print number in register $ao
   syscall
   li $v0, 10       # System call to exit to DOS
   syscall
```

Comment: which line is 19 ?

Comment: What toolchain/assembler?

Answer (score 3):

MIPS doesn't have a `blt` instruction.  Many MIPS assemblers support that opcode, though, as a pseudo instruction, which actually expands into several instructions that MIPS does have.

The assemblers that do support pseudo instructions usually have an option to turn them off.  Either that option is off in your environment, or, it doesn't support pseudo instructions in general, or it doesn't support exactly that pseudo instruction.

The `blt` operation:

```
blt $a0, $t0, label
```

is implemented by the assembler as follows:

```
slt $1, $a0, $t0      # set boolean temp $1 to $a0 < $t0
bne $1, $0, label     # branch on boolean temp is "true"
```

MIPS also does not have `bge` (for `>=`), but that can be had branching on the condition being false:

```
slt $1, $a0, $t0      # same as before
beq $1, $0, label     # branch on boolean temp is "false"
```

MIPS also does not have `ble` (for `<=`), but that can be had by

```
slt $1, $t0, $a0      # operands reversed, so we can use slt
beq $1, $0, label     # branch on boolean temp is "false"
```

---

Let's note that in order to support the expansion of many such pseudo instructions, MIPS environments reserve `$1` — aka `$at`, the "assembler temp" — because a temporary word of storage is needed to interconnect the two (or more) instructions in such expansions.  This practice is wasteful of valuable CPU registers to the assembly programmer (whereas compilers generally don't use pseudo instructions so not a problem for them).  Still, the more modern RISC V has chosen do to away with the reservation of a temporary register for the assembler to use in pseudo instruction expansion, and hence, does not to offer any pseudo instructions that require an extra temporary register.

Comment: technically psuedo instructions as well as calling conventions are the choice of the authors of the tools, as such which pseudo instructions if any and reserved registers are determined by the toolchain authors and not the ISA nor processor creators.   The isa creators tend to create a convention but you certainly do not have to follow it...and the tools we are most familiar with today tend to follow those, but there is a separation there, it is not a requirement (not enforceable anyway).